# How to access resources within application folder?

Tags: php, codeigniter

First of all, I am fully aware that a better implementation, putting resources folder alongside application (not inside), exists. So yeah.

Resources = js, css, images.

This is just really a requirement, so any ideas how? I tried it but it says 403 (Forbidden).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the possible solutions you can use

```
/applications
    /resources
      .htaccess
.htaccess
```

`.htaccess` of applications folder contains `Deny from all`

(it is CI default. which is the reason you get 403 Forbidden)

now make an `.htaccess` **inside** resources folder and keep it `Allow from all`

(so you are **just** allowing the resources folder to be accessible)

Comment: However, that would be unwise. There is [a reason for that .htaccess file](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/installation/): "By default, .htaccess files are included in each folder to help prevent direct access...". Translated, that means it protects you from yourself.

Comment: @machineaddict i know the reason and have edited answer too.
according to my answer you are just allowing the resources folder to be accessible **it wont have effect on other files and folders inside application folder, you can not access them**