# CodeIgniter: js and css files inside "application" folder. How to do?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I just installed CodeIgniter 3 and it seems that JS,CSS and images should be placed OUTSIDE `Application` folder. If not, link to those files does not run.

For many reasons I would like to have these kind of files inside `application/views` folder. I think that I should correctly set .htaccess file, but I would also like to "***lower my defenses less possible***".

What do you suggest?

Comment: Have you read the "Hide Your Files" section of [the user docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/security.html)? Allowing access to JS files in your code directory lowers your defenses significantly, even with a well-constructed .htaccess file. A reasonable compromise is to keep the files in your application folder but don't serve them from there; copy them to your webroot folder hierarchy during deploy (or during the startup script).

Comment: Duplicate of [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25197413/how-to-access-resources-within-application-folder/25197463#25197463)

Comment: My problem is that I have to add many plugins to existing CI installation, not only JS, but also PHP one. So, it seems very confusing split each plugin in php files inside application folder, js and css, outside it, etc. I would like to mantain all files of each plugin inside its own folder, and all inside "application" in order to have entire website in a unique folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is in the application folder .htaccss change deny all to allow all and then make sure you auto load url helper and the call your folder from where ever you want.

Update you could try this code in application/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|assets/css|assets/js|assets/ficheros|assets/img|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

rename assets folder to what you want if using xampp/wampp etc do not for get to stop and then restart it. Of course when paste code do not for get to remove the deny all.

Comment: To better understand: what risks could I have applying this solution? I would like to understand if risks are more theorical than practical or effectively there are high risks.

Comment: What else you could do is set htaccess in applications folder so it could allow css,images,and javascript but deny the rest.

Comment: ohhh ok, how to set in this way? Can you give me the right code?

Comment: I updated post try it out if you want. I have not used that code my self. but should only allow those folde/files.

Answer (score -2):

**Its simple, just delete the contens inside the .htaccess file. It worked for me.**

Comment: Blindly deleting the contents of a file is a terrible idea.